# How to clang-format the current buffer on save?

Tags: formatting, save, filetype-c

Whats the best way to clang-format a C/C++/GLSL a buffer on save, that does nothing in the case there is no clang-format file found for a project?

Answer (score 17):

You can add the following to your .vimrc

```
1. function FormatBuffer()
2.   if &modified && !empty(findfile('.clang-format', expand('%:p:h') . ';'))
3.     let cursor_pos = getpos('.')
4.     :%!clang-format
5.     call setpos('.', cursor_pos)
6.   endif
7. endfunction
8. 
9. autocmd BufWritePre *.h,*.hpp,*.c,*.cpp,*.vert,*.frag :call FormatBuffer()
```

#### What this does

1. Defines the function `FormatBuffer`.

   - You can call this at any time like so `:call FormatBuffer()`
2. Check whether the current buffer has been modified, and check if a `.clang-format` file is present in the same directory as the current file or any parent directories.
3. Save the current location of the cursor in the buffer.
4. Pass the contents of the current buffer to clang-format and replace the buffer contents with the output.

   - Note that this does mean if an error occurs during formatting, the current buffer will be replaced with the error message (e.g. if there is a syntax error in the .clang-format file). Of course the buffer contents can be recovered with a simple undo.
5. Restore the previous location of the cursor within the buffer.

   - Since the entire buffer gets erased and rewritten the cursor ends up at the beginning of the buffer.
6. Register a command hook that:

   - Is invoked just before a file is saved.
   - Only applies to C, CPP and GLSL files based on the file extension.
   - Calls the `FormatBuffer` function.

#### Sources:

[&mod, &modified](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27modified%27)

> *boolean (default off)*, *local to buffer*
>
> When on, the buffer is considered to be modified.  This option is set
>   when:
>
> 1. A change was made to the text since it was last written.  Using the
>      undo command to go back to the original text will reset the
>      option.  But undoing changes that were made before writing the
>      buffer will set the option again, since the text is different from
>      when it was written.
> 2. 'fileformat' or 'fileencoding' is different from its original
>      value.  The original value is set when the buffer is read or
>      written.  A ":set nomodified" command also resets the original
>      values to the current values and the 'modified' option will be
>      reset.

[findfile() builtin](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#findfile%28%29)

> **findfile({name} [, {path} [, {count}]])**
>
> Just like finddir(), but find a file instead of a directory.
>   Uses 'suffixesadd'.
>
> Example: 
>   `:echo findfile("tags.vim", ".;")`
>
> Searches from the directory of the current file upwards until
>   it finds the file "tags.vim".
>
> **finddir({name} [, {path} [, {count}]])**
>
> Find directory {name} in {path}.  Supports both downwards and
>   upwards recursive directory searches.  See `file-searching`
>   for the syntax of {path}.
>
> Returns the path of the first found match.  When the found
>   directory is below the current directory a relative path is
>   returned.  Otherwise a full path is returned.
>
> If {path} is omitted or empty then 'path' is used.
>   If the optional {count} is given, find {count}'s occurrence of
>   {name} in {path} instead of the first one.
>   When {count} is negative return all the matches in a List.
>
> This is quite similar to the ex-command :find.
>   {only available when compiled with the +file_in_path
>   feature}

[File search syntax](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#file-searching)

> **2) Upward search:**
>
> Here you can give a directory and then search the directory tree upward for
>   a file.  You could give stop-directories to limit the upward search.  The
>   stop-directories are appended to the path (for the 'path' option) or to
>   the filename (for the 'tags' option) with a ';'.  If you want several
>   stop-directories separate them with ';'.  If you want no stop-directory
>   ("search upward till the root directory) just use ';'.
>
> `/usr/include/sys;/usr`
>
> will search in:
>
> - `/usr/include/sys`
> - `/usr/include`
> - `/usr`
>
> If you use a relative path the upward search is started in Vim's current
>   directory or in the directory of the current file (if the relative path
>   starts with './' and 'd' is not included in 'cpoptions').
>
> If Vim's current path is `/u/user_x/work/release` and you do
>
> `:set path=include;/u/user_x`
>
> and then search for a file with gf the file is searched in:
>
> - `/u/user_x/work/release/include`
> - `/u/user_x/work/include`
> - `/u/user_x/include`

[Filename Modifiers](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#filename-modifiers)

> **:_%: ::8 ::p ::. ::~ ::h ::t ::r ::e ::s ::gs**
>
> **%:8 %:p %:. %:~ %:h %:t %:r %:e %:s %:gs**
>
> The file name modifiers can be used after "%", "#", "#n", "", "",
>   "" or "".  They are also used with the |fnamemodify()| function.
>   These are not available when Vim has been compiled without the |+modify_fname|
>   feature.
>
> These modifiers can be given, in this order:
>
> **:p**  Make file name a full path.  Must be the first modifier.  Also
>   changes "~/" (and "~user/" for Unix and VMS) to the path for
>   the home directory.  If the name is a directory a path
>   separator is added at the end.  For a file name that does not
>   exist and does not have an absolute path the result is
>   unpredictable.
>
> **:h**  Head of the file name (the last component and any separators
>   removed).  Cannot be used with :e, :r or :t.
>   Can be repeated to remove several components at the end.
>   When the file name ends in a path separator, only the path
>   separator is removed.  Thus ":p:h" on a directory name results
>   on the directory name itself (without trailing slash).
>
> When the file name is an absolute path (starts with "/" for
>   Unix; "x:\" for MS-DOS, WIN32, OS/2; "drive:" for Amiga), that
>   part is not removed.  When there is no head (path is relative
>   to current directory) the result is empty.
>
> Examples, when the file name is "src/version.c", current dir
>   "/home/mool/vim":
>
> - :p            /home/mool/vim/src/version.c
> - :p:.                     src/version.c
> - :p:~               ~/vim/src/version.c
> - :h                       src
> - :p:h          /home/mool/vim/src
> - :p:h:h        /home/mool/vim
> - :t                       version.c
> - :p:t                     version.c
> - :r                       src/version
> - :p:r          /home/mool/vim/src/version
> - :t:r                     version
> - :e                           c
> - :s?version?main?             src/main.c
> - :s?version?main?:p    /home/mool/vim/src/main.c
> - :p:gs?/?\?       \home\mool\vim\src\version.c

[Defining autocmds](https://elias.rhi.hi.is/vim/autocmd.html#autocmd-define)

> **:au[tocmd] [group] {event} {pat} [nested] {cmd}**
>
> *Add {cmd} to the list of commands that Vim will
>   execute automatically on {event} for a file matching
>   {pat}.  Vim always adds the {cmd} after existing
>   autocommands, so that the autocommands execute in the
>   order in which they were given.  See |autocmd-nested|
>   for [nested].*

[Events](https://elias.rhi.hi.is/vim/autocmd.html#autocmd-events)

> **BufWrite** or **BufWritePre**
>   *Before writing the whole buffer to a file.*
>
> **BufWritePost**
>   *After writing the whole buffer to a file
>                    (should undo the commands for BufWritePre)*.
>
> **BufWriteCmd**
>   *Before writing the whole buffer to a file.
>   Should do the writing of the file and reset
>   'modified' if successful.  The buffer contents
>   should not be changed. `|Cmd-event|`*

[Defining functions](https://elias.rhi.hi.is/vim/eval.html#:function)

> **:fu[nction][!] {name}([arguments]) [range] [abort]**
>
> Define a new function by the name {name}.  The name
>   must be made of alphanumeric characters and '_', and
>   must start with a capital or "s:" (see above).
>
> *function-argument* *a:var*
>
> An argument can be defined by giving its name.  In the
>   function this can then be used as "a:name" ("a:" for
>   argument).
>   Up to 20 arguments can be given, separated by commas.
>   Finally, an argument "..." can be specified, which
>   means that more arguments may be following.  In the
>   function they can be used as "a:1", "a:2", etc.  "a:0"
>   is set to the number of extra arguments (which can be
>   0).
>   When not using "...", the number of arguments in a
>   function call must be equal to the number of named
>   arguments.  When using "...", the number of arguments
>   may be larger.
>   It is also possible to define a function without any
>   arguments.  You must still supply the () then.
>   The body of the function follows in the next lines,
>   until the matching |:endfunction|.  It is allowed to
>   define another function inside a function body.
>
> *E127* *E122*
>
> When a function by this name already exists and [!] is
>   not used an error message is given.  When [!] is used,
>   an existing function is silently replaced.
>
> *a:firstline* *a:lastline*
>
> When the [range] argument is added, the function is
>   expected to take care of a range itself.  The range is
>   passed as "a:firstline" and "a:lastline".  If [range]
>   is excluded, ":{range}call" will call the function for
>   each line in the range, with the cursor on the start
>   of each line.  See |function-range-example|.
>   When the [abort] argument is added, the function will
>   abort as soon as an error is detected.
>   The last used search pattern and the redo command "."
>   will not be changed by the function.
>
> **:endf[unction]**
>
> The end of a function definition.  Must be on a line
>   by its own, without other commands.

Comment: The check for `.clang-format` should search all parent paths relative to the current file, similar to checks for `.git`.

Comment: @ideasman42 Good point. I've updated the answer to do this.

Comment: @ideasman42 Is there a reason you haven't accepted this answer? I've been using this for a few days now and it's working nicely.

Comment: There is an error searching up the parent directories: `findfile('.clang-format', expand('%:p:h') . ';')` works. After this, there is still the problem that this is slow on large files when the content is unmodified.

Comment: @ideasman42 you're right, I thought I tested that... well I made an edit to fix that and also added a check for whether the buffer is modified

Comment: Thanks, works great! (At first I didn't notice the `modified` part and was wondering why it was not working.)

Comment: When using `IncludeBlocks: Regroup` this has difficulties with the main category (0). Because it's operating on a buffer and not the file, it doesn't have the filename. Also play with `IncludeIsMainRegex` etc. to see the difference. Difficult to find what's the problem when you're running clang-format on the CLI and then within vim and the output is different! If a solution is possible, please tell. :-)

Comment: Ah, this will help in that case:

`:%!clang-format --assume-filename '%:p' `